# Faraday::ConnectionFailed - Couldn't connect to server. Error after updating to rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, faraday

An ActiveAdmin page I'm working on worked well in rails 5. For rails 6 the `update_attribute` was deprecated, so I changed those to `update` instead.

However, whenever I call `update(:attribute => true)` it comes up with this `Faraday::ConnectionFailed - Couldn't connect to server`. When I call `update(:attribute, true)`, it raises an argument error. When I remove this code, the page loads like normal but it doesn't when it's uncommented.

Is this a rails 6 thing? Not sure what's causing this